# Why isn't my <select> "font-family" property inheriting from <body>?

Tags: html, css, inheritance, font-family

My code:

```css
body {
    font-family:"Verdana",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
.myfont {
    font-family:"Verdana",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<body>
    Hello
    <select>
        <option>
            Hello
        </option>
    </select>
    <select class="myfont">
        <option>
            Hello
        </option>
    </select>
</body>
```

Why is the first `<select>` element not inheriting the `font-family` property from the specification for `<body>`?

If I have to change the font for a `<select>` why do I have to copy the style?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use:

```
select {
  font-family: inherit;
}
```

It'll work fine.  CSS is a little quirky when it comes to form controls.

Comment: how can you set individual <option> text **bold**? Because <option style='font-weight: bold'>bold item</option> doesn't work.

Comment: You'll probably get better responses if you ask this in a separate, new question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes font-family: inherit seems the best.
But otherwise:

```
  body, .myfont
  {
    font-family:Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  }
```

You can also replace '.myfont' for 'select' if you want all select elements to use this.

Hot tip. Do not use quotes around your font family names, it is not understood by all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

> If I have to change the font for a
>   "select" why do I have to copy the
>   style?

Just so you know, even if you did have to "copy the style", you don't have to *copy* the style like you've done above.

You would just apply the samy style to `body` and `.myfont` by doing this:

```
      .myfont, body 
      {
        font-family:"Verdana",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

James's answer seems the most elegant and correct to me, but I thought I'd just add another way to do it:

```
.myfont option {
     font-family: "Verdana"; /* etc */
}
```