# <select> element font is defaulting to MS Shell Dlg

Tags: html, css

I am using the following:

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: url(/Content/images/bg.png) no-repeat center top;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I don't style my select boxes but I notice using firebug that they have a font of MS Shell Dlg. Why is that and how can I make the font the same as the body? Also is the fact they use different fonts the same for all browsers?

Comment: What version of Windows you running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Browsers usually have a setting for the font of `select` elements in browser style sheets. These settings may be different across browsers. To make the font same as that of the body, set them the same, e.g.

```
body, select {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

Cf. to question [inherit “font-family” style in SELECT/OPTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413017/inherit-font-family-style-in-select-option). Using the `inherit` value is less reliable than an explicit setting, due to lack of support in older browsers (e.g., IE 7).

Note that the font size may be different, too, and it usually is—browsers typically have a somewhat reduced font size in form fields. If you wish to make the font size the same, too, add the following to the rule above:

```
   font-size: 100%;
```